# Jquery .load() is not working

Tags: jquery

I am trying to load a php page on clicking div into Data container. But it doesn't showing anything. Not even showing Error. Here is my code.

```
$(".Element").live("click",function(){

        alert("Loading Starts");

        var file = $(this).find(".file").text();

        $("#Viewer").show();

        var full = 'directory/file.php?curFile=' + file;
        alert(full);
        $("#Data").load( full , function(status){ if(status== "error") alert("There is an error");});
        alert("Loading Ends");

});
```

It doesn't showing anything in the #Data container.
Can anyone help?

Edit: Here is the html

```
<div class="Element">
    <div class="file" style="display:none">
         myfile.xml
    </div>
    <div>Some Text</div>
</div>


<div id="Viewer"> 
<p style="position:absolute; right:0px; top:0px;"onclick='$("#Viewer").hide();'>X</p>
<div id="Data"></div>
</div>
```

And the return of file variable is correct. I've checked via alert().

Comment: Live() is a deprecated jquery function

Comment: What is the url of the request is it sending?

Comment: 1) can you post your relevant HTML as well. 2) are you trying to click a div and load a different page?

Comment: Have you tried removing the callback function? $("#Data").load(full)

Comment: @jtheman - what if the OP is using an older version jquery in which it's not actually deprecated?

Comment: I only ask because I am not sure where you are getting the value of the variable 'status' that you are using in your callback function.

Comment: On a side note, you may want to take advantage of the Web Console in your browser, instead of using 'alert();' you can use 'console.log();' and avoid the annoying alert popups.

Comment: Yes, I know. But for a small thing, it is ok to use alert() as per my opinion.

Comment: Ok, cool, to each his won...anyway, back to my original question...have you tried .load() without your callback function?

Comment: @jtheman "Live() is a deprecated jquery function" while this may be true, it would be helpful if you followed that statement up with a link to some documentation, or point the OP in the right direction.  Seems a little big headed to make a general 'know it all' statement like that and then leave'em hanging.

Comment: Yes, I tried that also. doesn't work. And tried to call that php without parameters also. Both could not get me any results.

Comment: If the PHP file is in your main directory, put a backslash before the filename like so "/directory/file.php?curFile=' + file; " It could be as simple as this.  Though I am not sure of how your site is structured

Comment: @VIDesignz I'm constantly adding and removing elements on ajax request. So to get this onclick work I need to use live() function.

Comment: I know man...I didnt say not to! I was talking to 'jtheman'

Comment: @VIDesignz I tried that also !. That is also not working.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19657/discussion-between-videsignz-and-user1820644)

Comment: @VIDesignz and Gabe : As this is not an attempt to answer the actual question just a comment (ie things good to know of... ). I don't ever thought this was the real problem here but getting comments like this here on SO has several times lead myself both to new knowledge and finding errors. Reference is just a little too easy for having to post them here (Googling for "jquery live" directly points me to the fact it's deprecated)... Hope this satisfies you both.

Comment: @jtheman The OP is already here, asking a question...and if its so easy to google it, then its just as easy to post a link in your comment.

Answer (score -1):

Not exacly sure (after reading all those comment) what exactly is not working but I don'T see you append the data anywehre in your code.

To Append data to a element, use

```
 $('#data').append(full);
```

(i'm gessuing full is the data you want to show)
If you want to replace the data already in the div, use html like so:

```
 $('#data').html(full);
```

I really feels like i missed something, but those are the way to add data in a element with jquery, allong with .text().

As i'm editing this post cause of case, i would remind you that it is case sensitive. ;)

I jjst saw you use the load function. Sorry about that.. and it looks alright. to me..

Comment: `.load()` is supposed to work without any `.append()` or `.html()`, it's supposed to automatically replace the `$('selected_element')` with the loaded contents.

Comment: i saw the load, but after i posted my reply.. Check the last line. ;)